# Tilde notation of $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-i)!}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, algorithms, approximation, factorial

I'm trying to find the growth rate (tilde notation) of this function:

$$f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-i)!}$$

The $\sim$ notation is similar to the big O notation. However the $\sim$ notation is also interested in the coefficient of the fastest growing term.

For example: $3x^3 + 7x^2 - 90 \sim 3x^3$

Comment: Note that you can write the sum as
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-i)!}=n!\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{(n-i)!}=n!\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}$$

Comment: thanks for the help gammatester!

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ be the sum. You can show that $f(n)=\lfloor{en!}\rfloor$. See this MSE [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794500/how-many-ways-are-there-to-select-elements-from-a-set-without-replacement/2794538#2794538) for example

Answer (score 1):

The growth is same as $n!$ which is $\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^{n}$ from Stirling approximation. The reason is $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}$ is $O(1)$. In particular it is less than 3.

Comment: And the limit $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{i!} = e$. 

So, $\displaystyle 2n! \le \sum_{i=0}^n \dfrac{n!}{(n-i)!} < en!$ for all $n>0$.